# Pallindrome String is replaced by * character

Tags: java, string, substring

Input a string which contains some palindrome substrings. Find out the position of palindrome substrings if exist and replace it by *. (For example if input string is “`bob has a radar plane`” then it should convert in “`** has a ***** plane`”.

My code is given below.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Pallindrome_String {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        String sen;
        System.out.println("Enter the String: ");
        sen = in.nextLine();
        pallindrome(sen);

        in.close();
    }

    public static void pallindrome(String s) {
        int len = s.length();

        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            String res = "";
            if (s.charAt(i) == ' ') {
                res = s.substring(0, i);
                String rev = "";
                for (int j = res.length() - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
                    rev = rev + res.charAt(i);
                }
                if (rev.equals(res)) {
                    rev = "*";
                    System.out.print(rev + " ");
                } else {
                    System.out.print(res + " ");
                }
            }    
        }           
    }
}
```

Comment: And what is the problem?

Comment: The problem is that the String is index out of range. My problem solves But if you can improve my code so please do. Otherwise no problem.

Comment: Improve? It works, but you need better code? Or it still not works?

Answer (score 1):

There is a simpler, more efficient way of finding palindromes in Java. I'll explain the steps to implementing it.

first, after getting your input 'sen', you can use the split method of the String class to seperate each word.

```
sen = in.nextLine();
String[] splitted = s.split(" "); // seperates the string when there is a whitespace and stores the resulting words in an array
```

After you've got the words in an array, you can check each word and see if its a palindrome. To do so, you can read the word front to back and back to front and compare the result.

If u find a palindrome, store its index (position in the 'splitted' array). After you've gone through all the words in the 'splitted' array, you can then print out the appropriate number of *'s based on the length of the word.

Answer (score 1):

The split() will loose double spaces and punctuation in source string and make a lot of useless objects in memory. This is more correct solution. IMHO

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "Bob! Do you have a radar plane?";
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(s);
    Matcher m = Pattern.compile("[a-zA-Z]+").matcher(s);
    while (m.find()) {
        String word = m.group();
        if (word.length() == 0)
            continue;

        String reversed = new StringBuffer(word).reverse().toString();
        if (word.equalsIgnoreCase(reversed)) {
            StringBuilder replacement = new StringBuilder();
            for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++)
                replacement.append('*');
            sb.replace(m.start(), m.end(), replacement.toString());
        }
    }

    System.out.println(sb);
}
```

Comment: You can use `String.repeat(int count)` in Java 11 or later.

Comment: Or apache commons StringUtils in older Java